# SSRS MVC - Report Rendering Blank Page

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, report, ssrs-2008

I have implemented the ReportViewer in MVC. The only problem I'm having is that it renders a blank page. The toolbar is there, and the loading icon flashes for a second, but only a blank page is returned.

I've logged into the SSRS report manager and ran it through there and everything works fine. I'm at a loss of what to try next.

ReportsView(ASPX)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
    Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>ASPXView</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>

        <form id="Form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">          
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" 
            Font-Size="8pt" Height="600px" InteractiveDeviceInfos="(Collection)" 
            ProcessingMode="Remote" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" 
            WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" Width="100%">
            <ServerReport ReportServerUrl="http://localhost/ReportServer" ReportPath="/Reports/Requisition Summary Report" />
        </rsweb:ReportViewer>
        </form>        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace SP_MVC.Controllers
{
    public class ReportsController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Reports/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult ReportsView()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult ReportsControl()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Web Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SP_MVC.Properties.Settings.DBConnectionString"
      connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=DB;User ID=DBClient;Password=DBPassword;"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type = "Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
        <add namespace="Kendo.Mvc.UI" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Does it produce the same result in all browsers?

Comment: @DavidTansey I just tried Firefox,Chrome, and IE 8. All with the same results unfortunately

Comment: Here's a few things to try. Check the [ExecutionLog2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2009/01/05/executionlog2-view.aspx) of the ReportServer to see if the report is being run. Check the IIS log and fiddler to see if the requests are coming through. Check the SSRS Server's EventLog for hidden SSRS errors. Create an aspx page (or even test site) to check if ReportViewer works outside MVC. Also, if you haven't already, create a report with nothing but a static checkbox for all these tests to rule out SQL and datasets as the cause.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and fixed it by adding ZoomMode="PageWidth" and SizeToReportContent="true" to the ReportViewer tag.